# laravel validation unique rule

Tags: php, laravel

I try to use Illuminate\Validation as standalone library and it fails with unique rule. the error is: **Uncaught RuntimeException: Presence verifier has not been set.**
here is my code:

```
$fileLoader = new Translation\FileLoader(new Filesystem\Filesystem(), '');
$factory = new Validation\Factory( new Translation\Translator($fileLoader, 'en_US') );

$d = ['name' => 'te' ];
$rules = [
    'name' => [Rule::unique('page')],
];

$validator = $factory->make($d, $rules);

if($validator->fails()){
    $errors = $validator->errors();
    foreach($errors->all() as $message){
        d($message);
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look here https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/584

Comment: I've readed that issue. It's not my case. I use validator not in laravel app.

Comment: try to make database connections before executing rules/validation

Comment: connection to db is made. used eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unique` rule is meant to check the value to be unique in the database. The way the validator checks for "uniqueness" in the database is using a 'Presence verifier'. You didn't provide any Presence verifier and that's why you see the error. To provide a presence verifier you need to add this extra code

```
$presenceVerifier = new MyPresenceVerifier();
$factory->setPresenceVerifier($presenceVerifier);
```

where `MyPresenceVerifier` is an implementation of the `\Illuminate\Validation\PresenceVerifierInterface` contract. Since you are using the validator as a standalone library you will need to create your own implementation of the presence verifier for whatever database you are using. You can can find an example of implementation in the official Laravel repo:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Validation/DatabasePresenceVerifier.php

Comment: Thanks. I understand this. But don't know how to set presenceVerifier. Have you example with eloquent?

Comment: I've updated my reply with a link where you can find an example of implementation

Answer (score 1):

**Try this ::**

```
$this->validate($request, 
    ['email' => 'required|exists:users,email'],
    ['email.exists' => 'You are not registered User. Please register.']
);
```

**users** = Your table name

**email** = Your table field name

Comment: How it works with ignore() - Rule::unique('page')->ignore($id) ?